# ObservableCollection loses binding when I "new" it

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a ListBox on my UI that is bound to a property of ObservableCollection.  I set a new instance of the ObservableCollection into the property in the view model's constructor and I can add items to it with a button on the form.  These are visible in the list.

All is good.

However, if I reinitialize the property with *new* in the button callback, it breaks the binding and the UI no longer shows what is in the collection.

I assumed the binding would continue to look up the values of the property, but its presumably linked to a reference which is destroyed by the *new*.

Have I got this right?  Can anyone expand on how this is linked up?  Is there a way to rebind it when my view model has no knowledge of the view?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure you are raising a PropertyChangedEvent after you reintialize your collection. Raising this event will allow the view to handle changes to the property with the model having no knowledge of the view.

```
class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> List
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set 
        { 
            _list = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("List");
        }
    }

    public Model()
    {
        List.Add("why");
        List.Add("not");
        List.Add("these?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think based on your description that what you need to do is refactor the property that exposes your ObservableCollection so that it raises a PropertyChanged event also when it is assigned a new value.  Example:

```
public ObservableCollection<int> Integers
{
    get { return this.integers; }
    set {
        if (this.integers != value)
        {
            this.integers = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Integers");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Supposing you've implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on your ViewModel, you can raise the property changed event on your ObservableCollection whenever you assign a *new* value to it.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get; set; }

public void SomeMethod()
{
    MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    RaisePropertyChanged("MyList");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Updates to the `ObservableCollection` are handled by hooking in to the `CollectionChanged` event so when you create a new `ObservableCollection` your observer is still looking at the old collection.

Two simple suggestions would be either to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the class that contains the `ObservableCollection` and raising the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the collection property (don't forget to unhook from the old one first in your observer if it's your own code).

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _myCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection
{
    get { return _myCollection; }
    set
    {
        if(_myCollection == value)
            return;

        _myCollection = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MyCollection");
    }
}
```

A second, and the option I generally prefer is to just clear and repopulate the collection with your new data when it arrives.

```
public void HandleCollectionData(IEnumerable<string> incomingData)
{
    MyCollection.Clear();
    foreach(var item in incomingData)
    {
        MyCollection.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding each item to the observable collection increases the UI update roundrip.So you should avoid the second solution.

Comment: Agreed, the second approach here will increase the number of `CollectionChanged` calls and if it actually becomes an issues and you still want to avoid newing up a collection I would suggest implementing your own `ObservableCollection` with an AddRange method which would be quite easily done, but in most cases it wouldn't be a concern