# ObservableCollection is not updating data

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, observablecollection, async-await

i am getting problem with the observablecollection because it is not updating my view. it is getting data in it i have checked it. i have also make event its collection changed event but it is also not getting called. i don't know why is this happening here is my code..

```
public async Task GetActivityStudentCollection()
    {

        StudentActivityCollection =  await ViewModelLocator.ActivityViewModel.GetActivity(0, 8, 0, 20);

        StudentActivityCollection.CollectionChanged += StudentActivityCollection_CollectionChanged;
   //     RaisePropertyChanged("StudentActivityCollection");
    }

    void StudentActivityCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

i have bind this collection with listview like this.

```
 ActivityListViewSource.Source = ViewModelLocator.DashBoard.StudentActivityCollection;
```

this  **ViewModelLocator.ActivityViewModel.GetActivity(0, 8, 0, 20);** method is returning a collection that is i have binded(not working) but if i binded the collection directly to the collection that is going to be return it works..means if i binded like this(it work)..

```
ActivityListViewSource.Source = ViewModelLocator.ActivityViewModel.ActivityCollection;
```

i am sorry for my bad english.please try to understand the problem.
is it because of async method or what. any kind of help is appreciated..

Comment: Did you tried looping through the "ViewModelLocator.ActivityViewModel.ActivityCollection" and adding each object to the "StudentActivityCollection"?

Comment: no samar actually i have got the whole collection and just copied it to binded collection..because if suppose if collection is too big then it is not feasible..

Comment: Just try it for testing purpose. See if that is working. We can figure out a better way later.

Comment: @samar it is working..is there any to do it without it..

Comment: update the unswer i will mark it right..the way it is working is "var asd = await ViewModelLocator.ActivityViewModel.GetActivity(0, 8, 0, 20);

            foreach (var item in asd)
            {
                StudentActivityCollection.Add(item);
            }"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
public async Task GetActivityStudentCollection()
{

    var studentActivityColl =  await ViewModelLocator.ActivityViewModel.GetActivity(0, 8, 0, 20);

    foreach(var studentAct in studentActivityColl)
        StudentActivityCollection.Add(studentAct);

    StudentActivityCollection.CollectionChanged += StudentActivityCollection_CollectionChanged;
//     RaisePropertyChanged("StudentActivityCollection");
}
```

Comment: samar will you please work it out to do it without adding items one by one

Comment: I am not sure if this will work but try and implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface to the model which contains "StudentActivityCollection" and call the PropertyChanged event inside set of "StudentActivityCollection". Then try your original code. A complete implementation is given here. Try it and let me know if it works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783750/observablecollection-loses-binding-when-i-new-it

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't return a new collection from that method. You should pass an instance.

```
ObservableCollection studentActivityCollection = new ObservableCollection();

studentActivityCollection.CollectionChanged += StudentActivityCollection_CollectionChanged;

await ViewModelLocator.ActivityViewModel.GetActivity(studentActivityCollection, 0, 8, 0, 20);
```

Because all events are fired before you registered your event on it.

Comment: jeroen it is not the issue to fire this event..actually it is not updating data. means it just a check that i have applied and btw it is not working..thanks for your effort ...please try to understand the problem

Comment: I think the `StudentActivityCollection =  await ViewModelLocator.ActivityViewModel.GetActivity(0, 8, 0, 20);` is overwrites the old collection. It should add items, instead returning a new collection.